# bootstrap form validation for custom field

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a custom input field in my html

```
<form role="form" class="container">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="slNotificationType" class="control-label">Notification Type</label>
    <select id="slNotificationType" class="form-control" ng-model="inputNotificationData.notificationType"
    data-error="Please select an option" required>
        <option value="" selected hidden>Select Notification type</option>
        <option>Email</option>
    </select>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="btnCategory">Notification Category</label>
    <div class="form-control" required>
        <label>
            <input type="button" ng-click="showCategories()" value="Select Category">
                Selected :{{selectedCategory.name==null ? 'None' : selectedCategory.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
...
...
```

On showCategories() function I dispaly a pop-up, where user select a category. This popup display list of categories fetched from server in a tabular format. On selection of a category, the pop-up is closed and selected category is assigned to the variable `selectedCategory`. 
As part of form validation, I want to check whether user has selected any category or not. On other input fields in form, If I put "required" attribute, bootstrap will validate and display validation error message. But how do I put `required` property on input of type button?

Basically, I am trying to create a custom control that behaves like `<input type ="file">`, but instead of showing file browser, I have my own popup to select a category.

Comment: could you please paste it in jsbin so that code could be run here ?

Comment: It is difficult to paste entire code. But I have update my question, please check if you can understand it now.